# Oil spray against rust

Tags: rust, winter

How can I prepare car for winter in terms of anti-rust protection?

Someone told me that I can spray car with mix of ATF and WD-40. This way oil can creep into all the small places in car's body and protect it against rust.

Is it true?
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you can do that, but you're probably better off buying a properly formulated anti-rust product such as 'Waxoil' or similar. These can either be sprayed or brushed onto the underside of the car depending on the product in question.

Comment: I'm told that "Waxoil" is the best, but I've used LPS-3 Rust Inhibitor with pretty good success.

Comment: Does Waxoil wash off? I head that anti-rust protection that hardens will eventually (after few years) crack and water will be accumulating which leads to accelerated rusting

Comment: IIRC Waxoil do two versions, either the thicker paint type that hardens, or a thinner oil that doesn't harden, but needs to be re-applied each winter

Comment: I should probably add a word of caution.  When applying anti-rust products to the underside of a car, be careful not to block any of the factory designed drainage holes because of the car cannot drain rain water, pockets of rust will appear in box sections within the body of the car.

Answer (score 1):

as said by Nick in his answer you should use rust inhibitor, but if you want a cheaper method then use grease on the rusted surface and it will prevent rust until you wipe it off, but use carefully or you will quickly end up with grease marks all over your car which will take additional effort to properly clean